A set of transpositions is a minimal generating set for $S_{n}$ if and only if the product of all of its elements is a $n$-cycle
$$
\def\T{\mathcal{T}}
\def\Sym{\operatorname{Sym}}
$$
In the book Algebraic Graph Theory by Godsil and Royle, we have this lemma:

Lemma. Let $\T$ be a set of transpositions from $\Sym(n)$. Then the following are equivalent:

(a)$\T$ is a minimal generating set for $\Sym(n)$
(b) The graph of $\T$ is a tree.
(c) The product of the elements of $\T$ in any order is a cycle of length $n$.


Where the graph of $T$ is the one with vertices $\{1,\dots,n\}$ with two numbers connected by an edge if and only if their transposition is in $T$. The authors leave the equivalence of (c) with the rest as an exercise, which I'm finding it hard to do. I'm able to prove that (c) implies (b) by, given a cycle in the graph of $T$, finding a clever ordering of the transpositions that fixes an element. (And also, if the graph of $T$ is disconnected, I can order the transpositions such that they result in a product of disjoint permutations).
But I'm not sure how to proceed with the other direction. I tried, given an ordering that doesn't lead to a $n$-cycle, find either a cycle in graph of $T$, or prove that $T$ is not connected. I thought if the product was a product of two disjoint cycles I'd be able to prove that $T$ is not connected, but then found a counterexample to that. Tried to construct a cycle given a fixed point of the product but failed too. Any ideas?

Proof by induction on $n$: the base case is $n=2$, which is clear.
Assume (b) and let $x$ be a leaf in the graph, with $x$ joined to the unique point $y$.
A product of the transpositions in $\mathcal{T}$ has the form $\sigma = \sigma_1(x,y) \sigma_2$ where $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ are products of transpositions in $\mathcal{T_1}$, and $\mathcal{T_2}$ with $\mathcal{T}$ the disjoint union of  $\mathcal{T_1}$,  $\mathcal{T_2}$, and $(x,y)$.
By induction, $\sigma_1\sigma_2$ is an $(n-1)$-cycle on the points other than $x$.
I'll compose permutations from left to right. Let $a=y^{\sigma_1^{-1}}$ and $b=y^{\sigma_2}$,
so $a^{\sigma_1\sigma_2}=b$.
Then $a^\sigma = x$, $x^\sigma = b$, and  $c^\sigma = c^{\sigma_1\sigma_2}$ for $c \ne a,b,x$.
So the point $x$ is inserted between $a$ and $b$ in the $(n-1)$-cycle $\sigma_1\sigma_2$, and hence $\sigma$ is an $n$-cycle.

Very simple, thank you!
